# Making US Topo-like PDFs using ArcGIS Desktop and TerraGo Publisher?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I have tried making a GeoPDF like the one from US Topo PDFS using ArcGIS and TerraGo Publisher. They are nothing alike.

Does anyone know how they are made?

I am specifically looking for a zooming capability of the PDF and the ability to resolve spatially especially when it comes to cluttered datasets which the US topo maps do. Something similar to what happens in GIS software when you zoom in to a cluttered (lots of data in one point) dataset.

I have point, polygon and raster datasets in the same layer that I need to export to a US topo-like pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is get your map conforming to the scale-dependent visibility you want in ArcMap. Do this by right clicking on the layer in the Table of Contents (TOC) and select "Visible Scale Range" and set your minimum and maximum scales. Alternatively, you can right click the layer and select "Properties" and enter the minimum and maximum scales on the "General" tab.

Next you will have to open Publisher's "Export Configuration" dialog. On the "Layers" pane check "Maintain Visible Scale Range Settings". You can also consolidate multiple related layers in ArcMap's TOC into a single logical layer without affecting their independent scale-dependent visibility.